# How can I cancel an appointment politely?

Tags: politeness, phone-calls

I have never gone to a dentist, maybe just one or twice in my entire life. I found a dentist who has his office next to my home and in my desperation for my dental hygiene, I made an appointment for the next week with him.

However, I found another dentist who offered me the same service for a lower price. How can I cancel the first appointment that I made in a polite way? Please keep in mind that his office is next to my home, so it's probable that I could see him someday.

Comment: What are you considering doing and why are you afraid it won't be polite enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Medical providers would be tickled pink to have you cancel your appointment rather than just not show up.  They receive many cancellations per week and are used to this happening.  When you cancel, they can use that slot for someone else.  if you don't show up, they lose money on that missed patient care opportunity.  So they have an incentive to be kind to you when you cancel.

How to cancel it kindly?  Call the office and tell them that you want to cancel your appointment.  Most of the time, they don't ask for the reasoning behind it.  If they do ask, merely tell them the truth: "I've scheduled this with a different dentist."  In decades of making and cancelling appointments, it's been seldom that I've even been asked that question and have never been asked a follow-up question, such as "why?"